# How to pass values to the user defined variable in jmeter's jmx file via robot framework

Tags: jmeter, robotframework

I have a JMX file in which "Number of Threads (users):" is defined as a variable "${__P(threads)}.

In robot-framework, how to pass values to this user defined variable in the jmx file via keywords defined in JMeterLib.

Example: How to include the same in the below keyword syntax of JMeterLib:-

```
run jmeter  D:/apache-jmeter-2.12/bin/jmeter.bat    D:/Tests/Test1Thread1Loop.jmx   D:/Tests/output1.jtl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updating this answer**:

The command should be executed using below syntax [-Jthreads can be passed as 'Jthreads=10' or 'Jthreads 10']:

```
run jmeter  D:/apache-jmeter-2.12/bin/jmeter.bat    D:/Tests/Test1Thread1Loop.jmx   D:/Tests/output1.jtl -Jthreads=10
```

But still, I was getting an error as updated in the comment in response to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65889566/14795343. Thanks to Dmitri T and the response in github https://github.com/kowalpy/Robot-Framework-JMeter-Library/issues/6#issuecomment-793596283.

After analysis, it is found that this error occurred because the jmeter library for robot framework https://github.com/kowalpy/Robot-Framework-JMeter-Library is running in Python3 version in my test environment, but library is originally developed in Python 2.7.5 version. In nutshell, it due to python version compatibility.

And so, there is a particular command in the class "JMeterClasses.py" that was not recognized in Python 3 version due to which the error `"AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'split'"` is thrown.

Then updated the below method in "JMeterClasses.py".

```
Old:
    def listOtherParams(self):
        self.params = []
        if not self.paramsStr == "":
            self.params = string.split(self.paramsStr)

Updated (string is modified as str, as highlighted below):
    def listOtherParams(self):
        self.params = []
        if not self.paramsStr == "":
            self.params = str.split(self.paramsStr)
```

It worked for me after modifying the above method.

**Note**: You can find the "JMeterClasses.py" in the site-packages/dist-packages folder [Example Path: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/].

Comment: i tried the above solution but it is not working :(

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeterLib documentation](https://kowalpy.github.io/Robot-Framework-JMeter-Library/JMeterLib.html#Run%20Jmeter)

> Run Jmeter Analyse Jtl     jmeterPath, testPlanPath, logFilePath, otherParams=

[image]

So my expectation is that you need to pass this property value via -J command-line argument like:

```
run jmeter  D:/apache-jmeter-2.12/bin/jmeter.bat    D:/Tests/Test1Thread1Loop.jmx   D:/Tests/output1.jtl -Jthreads=1234
```

---

Also be aware that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) and your version 2.12 is 7 years old so it might be a good idea for considering upgrading so I would recommend obtaining [JMeter 5.4](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter5-4-new-features-and-abilities) (or whatever is the latest version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) or at least [JMeter 3.3](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-3.3.zip) which is supported by the wrapper library.

Comment: When I tried the same, it throws "AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'split'". Command used is "run jmeter    ${jmeter_install_path}    ${jmeter_jmx_path}    ${jmeter_log_path}    -Jthreads=10". What could be the reason?

Comment: robot-framework version = 3.2.2 ; Python version = 3.9.0 ; jmeter version = 5.4.1