# Attribute error while executing jmeter script with robotframework

Tags: jmeter, robotframework, jmeter-3.2

I am trying to execute [jmeter with Robot Framework](https://kowalpy.github.io/Robot-Framework-JMeter-Library/JMeterLib.html) but getting attribute error when I tried to pass extra parameter. I tried below solution but it doesn't work.

[How to pass values to the user defined variable in jmeter's jmx file via robot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65889454/how-to-pass-values-to-the-user-defined-variable-in-jmeters-jmx-file-via-robot-f)

Error:

```
robot TestCases/TC2_jmeter.robot 
==============================================================================
TC2 jmeter                                                                    
==============================================================================
Get_weather_info                                                      | FAIL |
AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'split'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TC2 jmeter                                                            | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
```

Comment: Show the code please and mark which keyword throws the error and add the backtrace as well please.

Comment: Hi,

below is the code and i am passing the parameter "-JCity1=10"  which is the value for the variable created in jmeter.Ths specific parameter is throwing the error
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

*** Test Cases ***
Get_weather_info

    Run Jmeter   /home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/jmeter.sh    /home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/HTTP Request.jmx  /home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/logs/log.jtl  -JCity1=10

Comment: Thank you, please edit the question and put the code there and please also format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like usage of a [deprecated string function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#deprecated-string-functions)

If you're using [this library](https://github.com/kowalpy/Robot-Framework-JMeter-Library) then it supposed to work with Python 2.7, I think you should be able to [still get it](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/), or alternatively identify and re-write the problematic piece of the library, it's open source in any case.

In general you should not need any extra libraries, it's quite possible to [kick off a JMeter test in non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) or [generate a HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report) using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module